# How do you add a link to requirements.txt?

Tags: python, git, heroku

I am trying to include the link `https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz` in my `requirements.txt`, for deployment on `Heroku`.

All my current requirements are formatted as packages. How do you format a `.tar.gz` download link when adding it to requirements? I tried `-e https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0.tar.gz` however, that resulting in an error message saying it requires a `url beginning with svn+, git+, hg+, or bzr+`

The main github page for the model I'm trying to include is located here: https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just put the full HTTPS URL in your requirements file. (`-e` is only for editable installs.)